# SSRS Reports ... and exporting properties for PDF

Tags: reporting, reporting-services

Iam using local version with VS  2010 and C#
I had a png image in the Report and it displayed great at the report (ReportViewer) but at pdf after exporting it got pixelated!.. I switched it to jpg and the quality is a lot better but not as good as the report..
Iknow about the issue of dpi problem but i dont know what to do.... or how to change settings for pdf export!